# Mounting a camera as a disk from command line

Tags: command-line, mount, udev, camera

I would like to mount my Nikon Coolpix camera as a disk on my CentOS 7. Following

http://hintshop.ludvig.co.nz/show/persistent-names-usb-serial-devices/

and

https://www.suse.com/communities/blog/manually-mounting-a-usb-flash-drive-in-linux/

I have found my camera's data in dmesg:

```
[  559.605914] usb 2-1.2: new high-speed USB device number 4 using ehci-pci
[  559.694657] usb 2-1.2: New USB device found, idVendor=04b0, idProduct=0360
[  559.694664] usb 2-1.2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[  559.694669] usb 2-1.2: Product: NIKON DSC COOLPIX L31-PTP
[  559.694672] usb 2-1.2: Manufacturer: NIKON
[  559.694676] usb 2-1.2: SerialNumber: VNA871EA41018279
```

and so created

```
/etc/udev/rules.d/99-usb-nikon.rules
```

with the content

```
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="04b0", ATTRS{idProduct}=="0360", ATTRS{serial}=="VNA871EA41018279", SYMLINK+="nikon"
```

I unplugged my camera and plugged it again, so `/dev/nikon` now points to the proper device file:

```
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 15 Mar 18 17:34 /dev/nikon -> bus/usb/002/006
```

which is a character device file:

```
crw-rw-r--+ 1 root root 189, 133 Mar 18 17:34 /dev/bus/usb/002/006
```

trying to mount it I get

```
$ sudo mount /dev/nikon /mnt/nikon
mount:  /dev/bus/usb/002/006 is not a block device
```

What should I do here to mount my camera device file as a disk? Should I use mknod somehow to create a block device file and then mount it?

Comment: Check if your camera has a menu setup option to go to mass-storage mode instead of PTP. If it does not you need to look at utilities that manage PTP; google suggests *gtkam*, gnome *shotwell*.

Comment: mass-storage mode means it will be a block device?

Comment: Yes, it should appear as a mountable block device and you should be able to read/write files on the camera's sdcard (if that is what it uses).

Answer (score 10):

Only way I found to mount a camera which uses solely PTP, is to use gphotofs with Gphoto2:

```
sudo apt-get install gphoto2 gphotofs
```

mounting:

```
gphotofs /mnt/mountlocation
```

unmounting:

```
fusermount -u /mnt/mountlocation
```

Comment: Perfect, works with my Nikon Z30